# Compiling php with curl, where is curl installed?

Tags: php, linux, curl, installation, compilation

I need to specify a directory when compiling php with `--with-curl=`

The curl binary is located at `/usr/bin/curl`

`curl -V` gives me

```
curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
```

`locate curl` gives me

```
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3.0.0
```

*removed /usr/share/... and other irrelevant files*

**UPDATE**

Tried `--with-curl=/usr/lib64` and `--with-curl=/usr/lib` although I'm pretty sure it's 64 bit.

```
checking for cURL support... yes
checking if we should use cURL for url streams... no
checking for cURL in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
    easy.h should be in <curl-dir>/include/curl/
```

**SOLUTION**

PHP requires curl-devel

Comment: for 64 bit ubuntu 17.** and after, curl is moved to /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl,
so just make a symlink 
cd /usr/include
sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/curl

Comment: @minhajul's comment was the solution for me //

Answer (score 119, accepted):

None of these will allow you to compile PHP with cURL enabled.

In order to compile with cURL, you need libcurl header files (.h files). They are usually found in `/usr/include/curl`. They generally are bundled in a separate *development* package.

Per example, to install libcurl in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Or CentOS:

```
sudo yum install curl-devel
```

Then you can just do:

```
./configure --with-curl # other options...
```

If you compile cURL manually, you can specify the path to the files without the `lib` or `include` suffix. (e.g.: `/usr/local` if cURL headers are in `/usr/local/include/curl`).

Comment: It's yum install curl-devel on centos, otherwise it's the right answer! Thanks!

Comment: gAMBOOKa: Yes, my bad, I realized it just before I saw your comment. Glad that was it. :)

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: Always keep in mind when compiling PHP (or any C program that is), that you will need the appropriate *devel* packages for any extension you want to compile that uses an external library.

Comment: on Ubuntu is `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

Comment: On CentOS it look like yum install libcurl-devel

Comment: libcurl4-gnutls-dev package DOES NOT include curl headers, you need to install libcurl4-openssl-dev instead:
$sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

Answer (score 21):

> **For Ubuntu 17.0 +**

Adding to @netcoder answer above, 
If you are using Ubuntu 17+, installing libcurl header files is half of the solution. The installation path in ubuntu 17.0+ is different than the installation path in older Ubuntu version. After installing libcurl, you will still get the "cURL not found" error. You need to perform one extra step (as suggested by @minhajul in the OP comment section).

Add a symlink in /usr/include of the cURL installation folder (cURL installation path in Ubuntu 17.0.4 is /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl).

My server was running Ubuntu 17.0.4, the commands to enable cURL support were

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Then create a link to cURL installation

```
cd /usr/include
sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu/curl
```

Comment: This actually solved the issue I had on Ubuntu 18.04 while compiling PHP-5.3.22

Comment: Thanks! the symlink fixed it for me on Ubuntu 20.04 and compiling `PHP 5.3.29` with `libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Answer (score 2):

Try just --with-curl, without specifying a location, and see if it'll find it by itself.

Comment: I did, it couldn't find it at the default location

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to compile a **64bit version**(x86_64) of php use:  `/usr/lib64/`

For architectures (i386 ... i686) use `/usr/lib/`

I recommend compiling php to the same architecture as apache. As you're using a 64bit linux i asume your apache is also compiled for x86_64.

Comment: Apache is compiled for X86_64, so is my centOS installation. Since curl was installed with it, I'm guessing curl is 64bit as well.

Comment: Yep, The curl executable is 64bit, but it also installed 32bit versions of the library(*.so files) so 32bit application can also be linked with the curl library.

Answer (score 0):

php curl lib is just a wrapper of cUrl, so, first of all, you should install cUrl.
Download the cUrl source to your linux server. Then, use the follow commands to install:

```
tar zxvf cUrl_src_taz
cd cUrl_src_taz
./configure --prefix=/curl/install/home
make
make test    (optional)
make install
ln -s  /curl/install/home/bin/curl-config /usr/bin/curl-config
```

Then, copy the head files in the "/curl/install/home/include/" to "/usr/local/include".   After all above steps done, the php curl extension configuration could find the original curl, and you can use the standard php extension method to install php curl.
Hope it helps you, :)