# change curl extension in php(xampp)?

Tags: php, apache, curl, xampp, http2

I have recently build curl with http2 support using visual studio. I have tested the curl.exe on command prompt. It is working as expected.

My requirement is that i have to use this built curl in my website running in xampp.

I know that the php in xampp already has its curl extension. It is in the file `php.ini` on line 878.

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

It is in .dll
How can i change this so that it points to my built curl.

If it is not possible in xampp, you can suggest some other away. But my requirement is that i have to use this built curl in my php project.

Thanks.

Comment: `php_curl.dll` is a PHP module and not cURL itself.

Comment: ok. How can i make my built curl work in php?

Comment: You have to download and build the PHP Source and not some random command line curl program

Comment: This might be informative http://stackoverflow.com/q/4976971/3885509

Comment: So might this https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: ok. I understood now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your version of the DLL's into the `\xammp\php\ext` folder. That is where PHP gets them from, and thats all you need to do apart from restart Apache.

Better make a backup of the originals in case yours dont work

Comment: i have .exe file. I do not have the .dll file.. Can u suggest a workaround?

Comment: Then you have compiled the extensions wrong or you are not actually compiling the php_curl extensions

Comment: i have compiled these from source. It is working perfectly on cmd. I just have to make it work in my php project.

Comment: What source exactly did you compile?