# Docker and php extension

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, debian

I try to install php extension in my container (debian Buster), but i have a lot off issues :

`E: Package 'php7.3-XXXX' has no installation candidate`

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

RUN apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y \
       git \
       vim \
       curl \
       bash \
       software-properties-common \
       lsb-release \
       gnupg

RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    && curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y \
    php7.3-common \
    php7.3-cli \
    php7.3-mysql \
    php7.3-curl \
    php7.3-xml \
    php7.3-mbstring \
    php7.3-intl \
    php7.3-zip \
    php7.3-json \
    php7.3-gd

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY ./ /var/www/html/

RUN chmod +rwx /var/www/html/prestashop.zip

CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I have trying install without extension packages. Same issues.

I can't understand why I can't install PHP extensions. I have the same problems no matter what PHP image I use.

There's one thing I must be missing.

Any ideas ?

Thx

Answer (score -1):

Use the `docker-php-ext-install` instead of the `apt install php7.3-XXX` (you are already using it to install the `zip` extension`).

In the [PHP Docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) there is an explanation on how to use it on topic **How to install more PHP extensions**.

So your dockerfile should be something like this:

```
#...
RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list \
    && curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    curl \
    xml \
    mbstring \
    intl \
    zip \
    json \
    gd
#...
```

Note that I'm not installing the `common` (no need for installing), nor the `cli` lib. If you need the `cli` library I suggest reading this tutorial: [How to install PHP extension into cli](https://blog.docksal.io/how-to-install-php-extension-into-cli-e3fd11b963cc).

Your Docker seems to have some other issues, including with cURL ([this topic might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976971/compiling-php-with-curl-where-is-curl-installed)) and with `https://packages.sury.org/php` signature, but those topics are too above the asked.